# Bluebird cancellation with await

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

This code is working correctly:

```
let promise;
try {
    promise = parent();
    //but I want: await parent();
    await continueStack();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught error in endpoint');
}

eventBus.on('stop::all', () => {
    console.warn('Caught stop::all event');
    promise.cancel();
});
```

It's cancelling promise on event emitted from other part of program. My problem is that I can not have `await parent()` because then listening for event is not executed yet. If I change to this:

```
let promise;
eventBus.on('stop::all', () => {
    console.warn('Caught stop::all event');
    promise.cancel();
});

try {
    promise = await parent();
    await continueStack();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught error in endpoint');
}
```

then I have error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancel' of undefined

and it crash and `continueStack()` is never executed. How am I suppose to reconcile these?

---

I've created entire example with above scenerio:

https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/147dc2e0c44c8d64386253d563ff6db4

In order to run it you need to get both files, install package.json dependiecies and run cURL / Postman request GET to localhost:5000/test

Comment: what's the point? why do you want to use `await` there? plus, `promise = await parent();` stores the resolved value of the promise in `let promise`, not the promise itself. Therefore `promise.cancel` does not exist as you don't have the promise, only the resolved value.

Comment: Because I want to execute continueStack after parent and I'm returning new Promise from parent function.

Comment: who/what dispatches the `stop::all` event? Is there any chance that `parent()` would dispatch that event? basically intending to cancel the Promise it is going to return? Or is that a situation that can not happen?

Comment: Event is emitted from background process running on other thread. Basically I'm creating bot for dynamic web app game from electron app with selenium. Lets say `parent` is function which is looping over waypoints on the board. When background process detect that monster appear on the board I want to cancel `parent`. I'll create example in a second and edit post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the `promise` var to `parent`, and then awaiting it:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.config({
  cancellation: true,
})
const parent = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    resolve();
  }, 100);
});

const continueStack = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    resolve();
  }, 100);
});

let promise;

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('stop', function() {
  if(promise && promise.cancel){
    promise.cancel();
    console.log('promise cancelled');
  } else {
    console.log('somehow promise was not properly set at this point');
  }
});

setTimeout(_ => {
  emitter.emit('stop');
}, 80);

async function operation() {
  try {
  promise = parent;
  await promise;
  console.log('after promise. This log should never appear.');
  await continueStack;
    console.log('after wait 2. This log should never appear.');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Even if the promise is cancelled, this is not called.');
  }
}

operation();
```

(running that snippet with node will only log 'promise cancelled'): Nothing after `await promise` inside the async function is executed).

Some considerations:

- Promise.config is needed to set `cancellable` to true.
- `await` is not like a sleep. It does not block the javascript thread nor the event listener, or any event emitter. It just ensures that code following an `await` will wait for the awaited promised. But this only in the context of an async function.
- cancelling a Promise does not make the catch handler to fire. This puzzles me but I guess it is just how it works.

Comment: the `eventBus.on('stop::all'...)` part needs to be before `await promise` or it is pointless.

Comment: It has no chance to listen for event. Await works like sleep() function in other programming languages. So with your example listening for event is executed after parent and continueStack resolve therefore your code won't work

Comment: @Thomas you right, I edited my answer, I think not it works

Comment: But it's not behaviour that I want. I want to cancel only `parent` and I want `continueStack` to be executed. To be honest I dont really understand why from try block only parent is executed and this console's and continueStack not.

Comment: They are not executed because they are handlers of the first promise. By cancelling it, its handlers are cancelled. However, if you don't need the `parent()`  result to continue... why do you need it to resolve before calling `continueStack()`? They are pretty much independent, aren't they? Why do you need to `await parent()`?

Comment: Because `parent()` is doing something ingame which I create bot for. It's not resolving any value but it's doing something in this game and I want it to be fullfilled or canceled but either ways I want continueStack to execute. I managed to cancel it with assigning variable to returned promise as you adviced but now nothing after `await promise;` is executed. Nor the `console.log` and `await continueStack`. But I want it to keep running after cancelation. I updated my gist: https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/147dc2e0c44c8d64386253d563ff6db4

Comment: Is it achievable?

Comment: @dopeCode if `parent()` never resolves, if you `await` it, any following line in the same async function will never execute. The point of await is to 'block'  code until a promise resolves. At this point I'm pretty sure I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: So when it's cancelled it's not resolved/rejected? And when cancelled I can not do anything more in this `operation` function from your example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194481/discussion-between-sergeon-and-dopecode).